# How to create a Python Dataframe with columns of dynamic length with one-to-many relation to the first column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
Name Accounts   ColumnX     Fruits     Animals

A   HDFC        3000        Apple      Lion
    ICICI                   Banana
    Axis                    Plum
                            Mango
                            Guava
B   HDFC       38822.11     Apple      Giraffe
                            Mango
C   HDFC       308382.33    Plum       Hippo
    ICICI      181910       Orange
D   AXIS       40000        Peer       Elephant
    SBI                     Orange
                            Mango
```

Above is the example form in which I need my dataframe output to be. I'll be getting the data in a loop. So, either I can create a list of values for each column or if possible add them on the go.

Can someone please help me out on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to add the values with the loop to a list, and then add that list to the dataframe. The data frame can hold various relationships including the one described, so I dont see this being an issue

Comment: How do you add the these multiple lists ? For example for Name index and value A, I need to add 3 columns, each of different lengths.

Comment: `Accounts = ['HFDC', 'ICICI', 'Axis']   
Fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Plum', 'Mango', 'Guava']   

d = {'Name': 'A', 'Accounts': [Accounts], 'ColumnX': 3000, 'Fruits': [Fruits], 'Animals': 'Lion'}   
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)`    You can add the variable length columns as their own lists in the data frame, effectively tricking the df into thinking that it is of length 1

Comment: Hi Srivatsava, does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes David. Thanks a lot. I was able to get the desired output with some minor modifications to the above suggested idea.